# Inbox fails to update with new messages after reading one new message

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox

Several times now, I've noticed a problem with the Inbox where it doesn't properly show new messages. This only happens on tabs that have been open for a while, where I've already received and read an inbox message.

To reproduce:

- Open any page, for example the home page
- Wait until you receive a notification in your inbox
- Open the inbox and open the message in a new tab (via mouse middle-click). The notification will be marked as read and the new message indicator disappears.
- Wait until you receive a notification again
- The number on the inbox will properly appear, but when clicking it open, there is no message.
- Reload the page to see the new message.

Comment: There's a refresh button in the dialog you have to click to get it. It's by design IIRC

Comment: Am I missing something? All I see is "Mark as read" and an all/unread toggle. No refresh button.

Comment: It only shows up when there's something to refresh; i.e. when you get a notification and the number appears, but the inbox itself doesn't contain the notification

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep an eye out for that.

Comment: You can forcibly make it appear by, when you get a notification, opening a second tab, marking it as read in that tab, and opening the inbox in the first tab. The button then appears in the first tab

Comment: The relevant announcement: [Inbox improvements are live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/335251) – see the "Real-time inbox refreshing" section.